# How to convert a mixed measurement values in dataframe to a uniform measurement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns A and B,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({
                  'A':[1,3,7,19,80,120,14,2],
                  'B':['years','years','months','months','days','days','months','years',]
                  })
```

I want change the value of with uniform measurement of 'years' as in:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'A':[1,3,0.58,1.58,0.22,0.33,1.17,2],
                   'B':['years','years','years','years','years','years','years','years']
                  })
```

I tried the with following code but I get (ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().)

```
for x in df.B:
    if x== 'days':
        df['A']=df['A'].div(365).round(2)
    elif x== 'months':
        df['A']=df['A'].div(12).round(2)
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to assign values, where for rows corresponding to "B"=="months", divide the "A" value by 12, for rows corresponding to "B"=="days", divide the "A" value by 365, and all other cases, leave as is:

```
import numpy as np
df['A'] = np.select([df['B']=='months', df['B']=='days'], [df['A'].div(12), df['A'].div(365)], df['A']).round(2)
df['B'] = 'years'
```

Output:

```
      A      B
0  1.00  years
1  3.00  years
2  0.58  years
3  1.58  years
4  0.22  years
5  0.33  years
6  1.17  years
7  2.00  years
```

Answer (score 1):

The more pandorable way by far was provided by @enke, but I thought I would include a fix of your approach to illustrate the preferred way to iterate over a df. Rather than just a regular for loop, you want to use one of pandas builtin methods such as [iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iteritems.html). Notice that this uses two iteration variables instead of just one. However, before iterating this way, it's advisable to use a [vectorized approach](https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module3_IntroducingNumpy/VectorizedOperations.html) if possible since it's much faster.

```
years_list = []

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['B'] == 'days':
        years_list.append(row['A'] / 365)
    elif row['B'] == 'months':
        years_list.append(row['A'] / 12)
    elif row['B'] == 'years':
        years_list.append(row['A'])
    else:
        pass
    
df['years'] = years_list

df = df.round(2)
```